# Chrome Web Store asking for payments

Tags: chrome-web-store

I am working on a Chrome Web Store application, and plan to use the Chrome Web Store Payments. I could find the documentation on how to check if the user has paid, but I can't figure out how to offer the user to pay? How should I redirect him to the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should publish your app to test users.  If necessary add them to a google group and choose that group in the developer dashboard.  Of course you will need to enable payments for your app too.

Only these test users will be able to see the link, which you can find through the developer dashboard by clicking on your app's name.  This will make a link, which at the moment is constructed like this:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/YOUR_APPS_CHROME_STORE_NUMBER

This page will have an "Add to Chrome for $x" that they need to click to help you test your payment implementation.  This URL could be used for advertising as well.

Google advises to create a new app listing for the public release of your app.